# Carthage, Xcode 8 and code signing

Tags: xcode, code-signing, carthage

I'm trying to include some existing frameworks in a framework that I am creating.

Everything compiles in my framework just fine, but when I try to include my framework in an app, it crashes with the following message:

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E756029C-5B94-42DA-A783-7F9C27F32D84/ASMCL_Framework_Test_Project_01.app/Frameworks/ASMCLiOS.framework/ASMCLiOS
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E756029C-5B94-42DA-A783-7F9C27F32D84/ASMCL_Framework_Test_Project_01.app/Frameworks/ASMCLiOS.framework/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: required code signature missing for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E756029C-5B94-42DA-A783-7F9C27F32D84/ASMCL_Framework_Test_Project_01.app/Frameworks/ASMCLiOS.framework/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
```

I'm using Carthage to build my dependencies.  Is there a way to make Carthage sign these dependencies as it builds them?  Or, is there something else that I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I WAS able to get things working by:

- Used the BASH script in issue [#1401](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1401) and re-signed each framework
- In the "General" settings for my Target, I have the framework in the "Embedded Binaries" AND in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section.
- In the "Build Phases" section, I have the framework in the "Embed Frameworks" section and UNCHECKED the "Code Sign On Copy" checkbox.
- Note: I did NOT seem to need to add a "Copy Frameworks" section to make it work. (I'll be doing many builds and keeping an eye on this though)

So, I seem to be up and working now!  So, I am marking this question as answered.